# Can anybody help me figure out what the author did in this task?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

In the expression

> $$L = \lim_{x\to+\infty}x\bigg(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}\bigg(\frac{\ln(1+xe^{-x})}{x}+1\bigg)\bigg)$$

The author claims in the next step that

$$L = \lim_{x\to+\infty}x\bigg(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}\bigg)$$

Can anybody help me to understand how they got rid of
 $$\frac{\ln (1+xe^{-x})}{x+1}?$$

Comment: As $x$ goes to $\infty$, $xe^{-x}$ goes to zero, thus so does $\ln{1+xe^{-x}}$ and, of course, so must $\frac{\ln{1+xe^{-x}}}{x}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$L = \lim_{x\to+\infty}x\bigg(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}\bigg(\frac{\ln(1+xe^{-x})}{x}+1\bigg)\bigg)$$

This is equal to

$$L = \lim_{x\to+\infty}x\bigg(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}\frac{\ln(1+xe^{-x})}{x}\bigg)$$

Using the laws of limits, you can write

$$L = \lim_{x\to+\infty}x\bigg(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}\bigg)-\lim_{x\to +\infty}\ln(1+xe^{-x})\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

Looking at the last term, it's equal to

$$\lim_{x\to +\infty}\ln(1+xe^{-x})\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}$$

But $\frac{x}{e^x}=xe^{-x}\to 0$ as $x\to +\infty$ because exponential functions grow faster than polynomials. Hence, the last term is equal to $\ln(1)=0$. Because $\lim_{x\to +\infty}\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}=1$, the last expression vanishes and we have that

$$L = \lim_{x\to+\infty}x\bigg(\sqrt[3]{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}}-\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}}\bigg)$$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: @user644728 You're welcome.

Comment: The laws of limits do not allow for $\lim(f(x)-f(x))=\lim(f(x))-\lim(g(x))$ when $\lim(f(x))=\lim(g(x))=\infty$

Comment: @stressedout, I would instead distribute the square root over the log and the $+1$, then separate the piece with the log from the rest, using the additive law of limits.

Comment: @BarryCipra I think your way is better. I will edit my answer.

Comment: One question , the limits law does not apply only  when  lim(f(x))=lim(g(x))=∞, and no other value?

Comment: @user644728 We have to be careful when the limit of something is $\infty$ because that's not a real value and it can lead to fallacies if we're not careful. If we work over the extended real numbers, we see that some laws like $a + \infty = \infty$ for a real number $a$ hold while some laws are indeterminate and ill-defined like $\infty-\infty$.

Comment: Thank you so much ,you people are legends

Comment: @user644728, another example where you create problems is if you try writing $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(\sin^2x-(1-\cos^2x))=\lim_{x\to\infty}\sin^2x-\lim_{x\to\infty}(1-\cos^2x)$$ In this case the two limits on the right simply don't exist.